# Retrieve the minimum in Laravel relationship

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I working on App similar to CRM App(Customer Relation Management)

I have the following code that get array of `$ms` that assigned to user

```
   //check if contract end or not and active or inactive
  // and first_date_for_service < now()
    $ms= MaintenanceService::join('cus_contract','cus_contract.id','=','maintenance_service.contract_id')
        ->where('cus_contract.status','=','active')
        ->where('cus_contract.contract_end_at','>',Carbon::now())
        ->where('maintenance_service.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('maintenance_service.first_date_for_service','<', Carbon::now())
        ->get();
```

now i have array of `$ms` so i will loop over it as following

```
  for($x = 0; $x< count($ms);$x++) {
   // here i get all notifications for $ms[$x] in each loop using Eloquent
      return count($ms[$x]->notifications);
    }
```

The above code working well,but i need fetch the minimum firstly ,for example

in first loop the count of notifications **3**
and in the second count was **2**.

**but i need the min in first** so when `return $ms[$x]->notifications;` 
i need return the array that carries the min count in our case **2**

**Is there any way to achieve that ?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you only need the row with the lowest count of notifications or do you need all items sorted by notifications?

Comment: no i need all items to get the lowest count of  notifications for each customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try to sort `MaintenanceService` items by there `notifications` relationship count?

```
// check if contract end or not and active or inactive
// and first_date_for_service < now()
$ms= MaintenanceService::join('cus_contract','cus_contract.id','=','maintenance_service.contract_id')
    ->where('cus_contract.status','=','active')
    ->where('cus_contract.contract_end_at','>',Carbon::now())
    ->where('maintenance_service.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('maintenance_service.first_date_for_service','<', Carbon::now())
    ->get()
    // sort all by the notifications count
    ->sortBy(function($ms) {
        // assuming 'notifications' is a relationship within the MaintenanceService model
        return count($ms->notifications);
    });
```

Check more out about the `sortBy` method on the collections [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby).

**EDIT:**
And of course you need `sortByDesc` HIGH => LOW and `sortBy` for LOW => HIGH.

Comment: @JustUser Be aware that this suffers from the "N+1" problem. For every MaintenanceService object, you'll be running a separate query to get the notifications for the object. You can alleviate this issue using [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Add the `with()` method to your query: `MantenanceService::with('notifications')->join...`.

Answer (score -1):

To get the element with the lowest value of a column you can use the `min()` method available on *collections*

```
<?php

$ms = MaintenanceService::join('cus_contract','cus_contract.id','=','maintenance_service.contract_id')
    ->where('cus_contract.status','=','active')
    ->where('cus_contract.contract_end_at','>',Carbon::now())
    ->where('maintenance_service.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('maintenance_service.first_date_for_service','<', Carbon::now())
    ->get();

$lowest = $ms->min('notifications');
```

More info on collections:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections

All available collection methods:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods

---

**Side note**

To iterate through eloquent results you can just do a `foreach` on it as it treats it as an array when needed:

```
<?php

foreach($ms as $element) {
    $notifications = $element->notifications;
}
```

Comment: I think there misunderstand  i don't need  the min column if i want the min 
column i can do this `$ms[$x]->notifications->min();`
the second thing `notifications` is Eloquent method  not column 
**i need to get the min count of `notifications` relationship in for loop to be the start of looping**